# Insert value to input / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, dom-events

I have the following JS / HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="file" name="file_info" id="file_info">
    <div class="file_upload">
        <input type="file" id="file_upload" onchange="name();">
    </div>
<script>
    function name() {
        var fileName = document.getElementById("file_upload").value;
        var fnSplit = fileName.split(/[\/\\]/);
        fileName = fnSplit[fnSplit.length - 1];
      document.getElementById('file_info').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
    }
</script>
```

I want that after I upload file, the file-name will shown in the tput text, but this cide doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

**Update : The file name should be inside the input text**

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use innerHTML on input elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `script` element before the `input` element. You had better put the `script` element inside your `head` like this

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/utamew/3/)

**Have update the answer!**

Comment: Input elements don't use `innerHTML` either.  Probably want `value`.

Comment: The file name should be in sepreat input text

Comment: @Jonathan we can get the file path form file object element http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp

Comment: @BradChristie sorry, thanks for your opinion, I have checked the code and fixed it.

Comment: @NaveTseva You can check it now, I just forget update the link, the current revision is 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction()
            {
                var fileName =document.getElementById("file_upload").value;
                var fnSplit = fileName.split(/[\/\\]/);
                fileName = fnSplit[fnSplit.length - 1];

                document.getElementById('file_info').value = fileName
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" class="file" name="file_info" id="file_info">
        <div class="file_upload">
            <input type="file" id="file_upload" onchange="myFunction();">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Do it like this:

## HTML

```
<div class="file_upload">
    <input type="file" id="file_upload">
</div>
<div id="file_info"></div>
```

## JS

```
function name(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);

    reader.onload = function (event) {
        document.getElementById('file_info').innerHTML = "Filename: " + file.name + "\nContent: " + event.target.result;
    };

    reader.onerror = function () {
        alert('Unable to read ' + file.name);
    };
}

document.getElementById('file_upload').onchange = function () {
    name(this.files[0]);
};
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uYwbD/3/)

Comment: The file name should be in sepreat input